# Is there any way to split the tests into independent groups, each of which will run a fresh pytest run?

Tags: python, pytest

In my framework there is logic outside of tests/setup/conftest in which an instance is created that retrieves data from the database, which then, in the collect phase, forms the number of tests for taking into pytest.mark.parametrize.

I was faced with the fact that the amount of data in some cases is large enough that it generates 5 million tests. I optimized the system as best I could, but I exceed the memory consumption limit for docker 8GB; in my case, such a run at the peak of the collect phase consumes 11GB during the collect phase.

The idea came up to break them into subgroups; I can break the original data into database pieces that will be located locally. In total, in my case, each run will contain 200 thousand tests, which is quite acceptable for me.

The problem is that I would ideally like to organize the code in one run, let's say --batches args I can write the internal logic for generating a new parameterization for each, but I don’t know how to intercept pytest so that upon completion of one group of tests it starts a fresh run with another group of tests.

I tried the following options - a separate python script that runs pytest.main() in a loop with certain arguments like --batch_group 1, etc.

This method does not work because within this python process my instances with logic are initialized only once and run is essentially not fresh. Example below:

```
class Logger:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            print("Creating new instance")
            cls._instance = super(Logger, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

import pytest

def test_1():
    pytest.logger = Logger()
    print(f'{id(pytest.logger)=}')

def test_2():
    pytest.logger = Logger()
    print(f'{id(pytest.logger)=}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main(['-k', 'test_1'])
    pytest.main(['-k', 'test_2'])


id(pytest.logger) = 140325718144768
id(pytest.logger) = 140325718144768
```

That is, here the runs will not be fresh and independent, although pytest is launched with different arguments, but the singleton will work and the instance will not be redefined depending on the new data

The method of splitting tests after collection is not suitable, since in terms of memory consumption, each run will collect 5 million tests and crash. That is, you need to break into groups before the collect phases

Marking the tests with @pytest.mark also not suitable for me because in my case one mark can collect up to 4 millions of tests

The only way I have left is to simply use subprocess or bash to do independent pytest runs in a loop. But perhaps someone can suggest more elegant methods? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What I can offer

1. Using `subprocess` as you mentioned: 
   You can use `subprocess.run` to spawn a new Python process for each batch, thereby ensuring that there's no state carried over from one batch to the next.

```py
import subprocess

num_batches = 25  # Total number of batches you want
for i in range(num_batches):
    subprocess.run(["pytest", "--batch_group", str(i)])
```

2. Dynamic Test Generation: 
   A more pytest-native way is to generate tests dynamically. You can generate batches on-the-fly during the session start, and then generate only tests for the current batch. The main idea here is to utilize pytest hooks. 
   The advantage of this method is that you only collect and generate tests for the current batch group, thereby sidestepping memory issues.

```py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--batch_group", type=int, default=0, help="batch group number")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    batch_group = metafunc.config.getoption("batch_group")
    start, end = compute_batch_limits(batch_group)
    
    # Fetch the subset of data for the current batch_group
    data_for_batch = fetch_data_from_db(start, end)
    
    if "db_data" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("db_data", data_for_batch)

def compute_batch_limits(batch_group):
    # Compute the start and end limits for the data fetch query
    # based on the batch_group number
    # ...

def fetch_data_from_db(start, end):
    # Fetch a subset of data based on the start and end limits
    # ...
```

3. Pytest-xdist: 
   If you are not already using it, consider using the [pytest-xdist](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist), which allows for parallel test execution. This might help in distributing the load and speeding up the execution, though you'd still have to combine it with one of the above methods to tackle the memory constraint.
4. Consider whether there are ways to optimize or reduce the amount of data necessary for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I still think that the only way out for me is point 1 subprocess. pytest-xdist is not suitable for me because in single run, at least the main worker will still collect 5 million tests in the collect phase and only then distribute it between workers, and the problem itself lies precisely in collecting and not in running tests. At the time of the run after collect, my memory consumption in docker drops by 3Gb. Dynamic test generation is a way to organize tests inside each batch, for me this is not a problem.

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for a way to run pytest where, as a result of one run after collect -> test execution. I can return to the collect phase again without many processes/runs. Then I would have a solution to the problem of transferring data between runs, remaining batches, single report folder, etc.